# Using Surreal Numbers to measure function growth rate - Tetration?

Tags: asymptotics, cardinals, surreal-numbers

In "The Book of Numbers" by John H. Conway, pg. 299, he discusses the application of surreal numbers to quantifying the growth rate of functions.

He gives the following correspondences:
$$\begin{aligned}
\frac{1}{ω}&&\cdots&&&\ln x \\
n&&\cdots&&&x^n&&(n\text{ real}) \\
ω&&\cdots&&&e^x \\
ω + n &&\cdots&&&x^n e^x \\
nω &&\cdots&&&e^{nx} \\
ω^n &&\cdots&&&e^{x^n} \\
ω^ω &&\cdots&&&e^{e^x} \\
ω^{ω^ω} &&\cdots&&&e^{e^{e^x}} \\
ω^{ω^{ω^ω}} &&\cdots&&&e^{e^{e^{e^x}}} \\
\end{aligned}$$

Now here is my question:

The next number after an arbitrary number of $ω$'s should be $\epsilon_0$. But what should the corresponding function be? Obviously an infinitely nested exponential would diverge. I'm thinking it ***might*** be [tetration](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Tetration). i.e.

$$\begin{aligned}
\epsilon_0 &&\cdots&&& {^x}e \\
\end{aligned}$$

But this is a hunch. I'm not sure if this is provable. Thoughts?

Comment: My guess is any function whose "growth rate" is that the piecewise linear extension of $f:{\mathbb N} \rightarrow {\mathbb R}$ defined by $f(1) = e$ and $f(2) = e^e$ and $f(3) = e^{e^e}$ and $f(4) = e^{e^{e^e}}$ and $\ldots$

Comment: Yeah, that would be tetration. I know for a fact it would be at *least* $\epsilon_0$. But I'm not sure if it's greater.

Comment: You might be interested in [*An ordered set of arithmetic functions representing the least* $\epsilon$-*number*](https://doi.org/10.1002/malq.19750210115) by Levitz (1975) AND [*An ordinal bound for the set of polynomial functions with exponentiation*](https://doi.org/10.1007/BF02485393) by Levitz (1978; makes use of the least ordinal $\alpha$ such that $\;\epsilon_{\alpha} = \alpha)$ AND [*Skolem + tetration is well-ordered*](https://doi.org/10.1007/978-3-642-03073-4_2) by Barra/Gerhardy (2009).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Conway's correspondences are presented in a very informal way, so it's unclear what one would want to prove there. There is a way to make it formal, but it excludes numbers such as $\varepsilon_0$.

Still, there is a general *but conjectural* correspondence between surreal numbers and growth rates. In this picture, surreal number do not all correspond to growth rates of real-valued functions (of which there are too few, compared to the multiplicity of surreal numbers). Instead they are growth rates of functions defined on surreal numbers themselves.

In that correspondence, the number $\varepsilon_0$ corresponds to a function $E$ satisfying $E(x+1) = \exp(E(x))$ for all large $x$. So it is a form of tetration.

If you want to learn more about this correspondence, I suggest you read the survey article *On numbers, germs and transseries* of Aschenbrenner, vdDries and vdHoeven, or the introduction of my thesis "Hyperseries and surreal numbers". You can find both of them online.

Comment: Hi @nombre. Thank you for your answer. I have found your previous answer on this question https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3440434/surreal-numbers-and-function-growth?rq=1. It appears the Conway's method corresponds to the 1st method in the OP I linked, whereas you have linked to an interesting paper based on that OPs 2nd method.

I agree that Conway's method is informally presented. However, it appears to follow a definite rule - multiplying functions *adds* the surreal numbers representing them.

Is it an open question as to whether this can be further generalized?

Comment: @SSD Consider an ordered field $\mathcal{H}$ of growth rates of real-valued functions under pointwise sum and product, embedded into $\mathbf{No}$.
There is a natural valuation on $\mathbf{No}$, i.e. a group morphism $v \colon (\mathbf{No}^{\times},\cdot) \longrightarrow (\mathbf{No},+)$ with $v(a+b) \geq \min(v(a),v(b))$ if $a+b \neq 0$. If you take two growth rates $f,g \in \mathcal{H}$, then $v(f g) = v f+v g$.
So it is a matter of finding such fields $\mathcal{H}$ and embedding them into $\mathbf{No}$. (cont.)

Comment: (cont.) In fact all such fields embed into $\mathbf{No}$, so it is rather a matter of finding such fields and then "natural" embeddings. If you take $\mathcal{H}$ to be the closure under $\exp$ and $\log$ of Boshernitzan's Hardy field $\mathbb{R}(E,E',E'',...)$ where $E$ is as above, then there is a natural embedding, and this extends Conway's correspondences with $\varepsilon_0 \longleftrightarrow E$.

Comment: That's awesome. So then it appears your function satisfying $E(x+1) = exp(E(x))$ is precisely the tetration function that I and an additional commenter had initially suspected (but lacked the background to demonstrate). I.e. $E(0) = 1$, $E(1) = e$, $E(2) = e^e$,  $E(3) = e^{e^e}$, etc. Thanks for your insight!